# joint optimization problem with somewhat symmetric function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I have just brief question that the method that I use to solve optimization problem is legit.
I have function $\max_{x,y}F(x,y)$, and first order condition gives me following equation.
$$\frac{\partial F(x,y)}{\partial x}=(x-c')+g(x,y)-z(x,y)=0$$
$$\frac{\partial F(x,y)}{\partial y}=(y-c)-g(x,y)+z(x,y)=0$$ This is just arbitrary functional form..
To solve this equation, what I have done is to multiply $-1$ to the first equation.
$$\frac{\partial F(x,y)}{\partial x}=-(x-c')-g(x,y)+z(x,y)=0$$
as both $\frac{\partial F(x,y)}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial F(x,y)}{\partial y}$ are equal to $0$, I set $\frac{\partial F(x,y)}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial F(x,y)}{\partial y}$, then I wil have 
$$-(x-c')-g(x,y)+z(x,y)=(y-c)-g(x,y)+z(x,y)$$
$$-(x-c')=(y-c)$$
therefore function $F(x,y)$ is maximized at $x=c'$ and $y=c$.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: If I can do the way I did to solve the optimisational equation. and If my conclusion is correct.

Comment: No, you can only conclude that $-(x-c')=(y-c)$ at an extrema. Why would both sides be zero?

Comment: Because that is how I am supposed to find local maxima..

Comment: No, if $a+b=0$ and $c-b = 0$, you can conclude that $a+c = 0$ but not that $a=0, c=0$.

Comment: But $a=0$ and $b=0$ can be one of answer right?

Comment: It **can**, but, by itself, it does not imply that $a=b=0$.